# How to parse JSON query response

Tags: json, parsing

I am just a dabbler but currently working on an integration project and looking to parse a JSON response.  My query returns the results from the API call without issue but I need to only get certain collections from the response.  I haven't been able to work out the structure, any help greatly received.

A snapshot of the response of the query is:

```
object      {1}

    array       {1}
        response        {2}
             result     {1}
                Accounts        {1}
                    row     {2}
                        no  :   1
                        FL      [27]
                            0       {2}
                               val  :   ACCOUNTID
                               content  :   2715694000000200001
                            1       {2}
                               val  :   SMOWNERID
                               content  :   2715694000000170001
                            2       {2}
                               val  :   Account Owner
                               content  :   "Owner Name"
                            3       {2}
                               val  :   Account Name
                               content  :   "Customer Name"
                            4       {2}
                               val  :   Account Site
                               content  :   "Site"
                            5       {2}
                               val  :   Website
                               content  :   "www.example.com"
```

The information I particularly need is ACCOUNTID and Account Name, and I thought I could use something like:

response.result.Accounts.row.FL[0]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did your got for now? Any error information show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)